# How do I send/read data from device in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

How do I just create some data on device and then send/read it on the host?

I tried following but does not seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "vectors.h"
#include "sphere.h"
#include "shading.h"
#include "ray.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include <CL/cl.h>

#if defined __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#elif defined (WIN32)
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/freeglut_std.h>
#endif

#include <time.h>

VECTOR3D light;
SPHERE sphere[NSPHERES];
static PIXEL pixel;
VIEWPORT viewport;
VECTOR3D view_point;
VEC_BASIS camera_frame;
cl_double focal_distance;


double color;
//double kd_red, kd_green, kd_blue;
//double ks_red, ks_green, ks_blue;
double red, green, blue;
double light_intensity, ambi_light_intensity;
double theta, reflected_theta;

int bShadow = 0;

int direction[NSPHERES];

int intersection_object = -1; // none
double current_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff; // maximum positive double
double current_reflected_lambda = 0x7fefffffffffffff; // maximum positive double

// window identifier:
static int win;

void Timer (int obsolete) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, Timer, 0);
}

// opencl stuff
typedef struct cl_struct {
    cl_platform_id platform_id;
    cl_device_id device_id;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue queue;
} cl_struct;

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

void disp2(void) {

    int i,j;
    PIXEL* pCurrentPixel;
    PIXEL* pPixels;

    int VPWIDTH = viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin;
    int VPHEIGHT = viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin;

    pPixels = (PIXEL*)(viewport.pPixels);

    //clear all pixels:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // For all pixels:
    for (i=0; i<VPWIDTH; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<VPHEIGHT; j++) {

            pCurrentPixel = (PIXEL*)(pPixels + VPWIDTH*i + j);

            //set color for the current pixel:
            glColor3f(pCurrentPixel->rgb[0] , pCurrentPixel->rgb[1], pCurrentPixel->rgb[2]);

            // draw pixel
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2i(i, j);
            glEnd();
        } // j
    } //i

    //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init(void) {

    direction[0] = 1;
    direction[1] = 0;
    direction[2] = 1;

    pixel.i = 0;
    pixel.j = 0;

    // set scene:
    // 1. define viewport
    viewport.xvmin = -VIEWPLANE;
    viewport.yvmin = -VIEWPLANE;
    viewport.xvmax = VIEWPLANE;
    viewport.yvmax = VIEWPLANE;

    // 2. allocate enough space for pixels in viewport
    viewport.pPixels = (PIXEL *) malloc(sizeof(PIXEL) * (viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin) * (viewport.yvmax- viewport.yvmin));

    // 3. set camera:
    camera_frame.u.x = 1.0;
    camera_frame.u.y = 0.0;
    camera_frame.u.z = 0.0;

    camera_frame.v.x = 0.0;
    camera_frame.v.y = 1.0;
    camera_frame.v.z = 0.0;

    camera_frame.n.x = 0.0;
    camera_frame.n.y = 0.0;
    camera_frame.n.z = 1.0;

    view_point.x = (viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin) / 2.0 ;
    view_point.y = (viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin) / 2.0 ;
    view_point.z = 0.0;

    // 4. set light:
    light.x = view_point.x - 1300;
    light.y = view_point.y + 1300 ;
    light.z = view_point.z - 300;


    ambi_light_intensity = 1.0;
    light_intensity = 1.0;

    focal_distance = FOCALDIST;

    // 5. put spheres behind the viewport:
    sphere[0].radius = RADIUS/1.5;
    sphere[0].center.x  = view_point.x - (RADIUS+30);
    sphere[0].center.y  = view_point.y ;
    sphere[0].center.z  = view_point.z - focal_distance - (2*RADIUS+20);
    // the first sphere is blue:
    set_rgb_array(sphere[0].kd_rgb, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[0].ks_rgb, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[0].ka_rgb, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2);
    sphere[0].shininess = 100.0;
    sphere[0].mirror = false;

    sphere[1].radius = RADIUS/1.2;
    sphere[1].center.x  = view_point.x + 0;
    sphere[1].center.y  = view_point.y + 50;
    sphere[1].center.z  = view_point.z - focal_distance - (3*RADIUS+20);
    // the second sphere is green:
    set_rgb_array(sphere[1].kd_rgb, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[1].ks_rgb, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[1].ka_rgb, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0);
    sphere[1].shininess = 10.0;
    sphere[1].mirror = false;


    sphere[2].radius = RADIUS;
    sphere[2].center.x  = view_point.x + (2*RADIUS+30);
    sphere[2].center.y  = view_point.y + 100;
    sphere[2].center.z  = view_point.z - focal_distance - (4*RADIUS+20);
    // the third sphere is red:
    set_rgb_array(sphere[2].kd_rgb, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[2].ks_rgb, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[2].ka_rgb, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    sphere[2].shininess = 100.0;
    sphere[2].mirror = false;


    sphere[3].radius = 1*RADIUS;
    sphere[3].center.x  = view_point.x ;
    sphere[3].center.y  = view_point.y - 100*RADIUS-130;
    sphere[3].center.z  = view_point.z - focal_distance - (4*RADIUS+20);
    // the third sphere is red:
    set_rgb_array(sphere[3].kd_rgb, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[3].ks_rgb, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    set_rgb_array(sphere[3].ka_rgb, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    sphere[3].shininess = 100.0;
    sphere[3].mirror = false;

    // set clearing (background) color to white:
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // specify that ortgogonal 2D projection is to be used to
    // map context of 2D world coordinats to the screen. We use the
    // world-coordinate rectangle of the same aspect ratio as the display window
    // so ther is no distortion:
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, WINDOW, 0.0, WINDOW);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    clock_t startCPU, endCPU, startGPU, endGPU;

    // init glut:
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    // specify the display mode to be RGB and single buffering:
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    // specify the initial window position:
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    // specify the initial window size:
    glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW,WINDOW);
    // create the window and set title:
    win = glutCreateWindow("Basic Ray Tracer by Pa3cio, UL FRI");

    init();

    // Create the two input vectors
    int i, j, k, l;

    int VPWIDTH = viewport.xvmax - viewport.xvmin;
    int VPHEIGHT = viewport.yvmax - viewport.yvmin;

    // PIXEL* pixels = (PIXEL*) malloc(sizeof(PIXEL) * VPWIDTH * VPHEIGHT);
    PIXEL* pPixelsFromGPU = (PIXEL*) malloc(sizeof(PIXEL) * VPWIDTH * VPHEIGHT);

    PIXEL* pCurrentPixel;
    PIXEL* pPixels;
    RAY ray, shadow_ray;

    SPHERE_INTERSECTION intersection, current_intersection, shadow_ray_intersection;

    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("/home/rokj/sula/vpsa/seminarska/kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread( source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose( fp );

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs( platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1,
                          &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext( NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
    cl_mem output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY|CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,
                                      VPWIDTH * VPHEIGHT * sizeof(PIXEL), NULL, &ret);

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
                                                   (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "compute_ray", &ret);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&output);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 1\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(VECTOR3D), &view_point);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 2\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(VECTOR3D), &camera_frame.n);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 3\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(VECTOR3D), &camera_frame.u);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 4\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(VECTOR3D), &camera_frame.v);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 5\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_int), &viewport.xvmin);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 6\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 6, sizeof(cl_int), &viewport.yvmin);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 7\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 7, sizeof(cl_double), &focal_distance);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 7\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 8, sizeof(cl_int), &VPWIDTH);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 9\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 9, sizeof(cl_int), &VPHEIGHT);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fputs("error setting CL kernel arg 10\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    ret = clFinish(command_queue);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = VPWIDTH * VPHEIGHT; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 1024; // Divide work items into groups of 64

    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
                                 &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the memory buffer C on the device to the local variable C
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, output, CL_TRUE, 0,
                              VPWIDTH * VPHEIGHT * sizeof(PIXEL), pPixelsFromGPU, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Display the result to the screen
    //for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++)
    //    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", A[i], B[i], C[i]);

    // Clean up
//    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
//    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
//    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
//    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
//    ret = clReleaseMemObject(b_mem_obj);
//    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
//    ret = clReleaseContext(context);


    pPixels = (PIXEL*) (pPixelsFromGPU);

    // For all pixels:
    for (i=0; i<VPWIDTH; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<VPHEIGHT; j++) {    
            //pCurrentPixel = (PIXEL*)(pPixels + VPWIDTH*i + j);
            // here I try to get pixel set on GPU, but it does not work
            pCurrentPixel = &pPixels[i*VPWIDTH+j];

        } //j
    } //i

    viewport.pPixels = (PIXEL*) (pPixelsFromGPU);

    // register callback function to display graphics:
    glutDisplayFunc(disp2);
    // call Timer():
    Timer(0);
    // enter tha main loop and process events:
    glutMainLoop();

    free(pPixelsFromGPU);

    return 0;
}
```

Definitions on host:

```
#include <CL/cl.h>

#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H

#define _BLINNPHONG
//#define _LAMBERT
//#define _NOSHADING

#define NSPHERES 4
#define VIEWPLANE 500
#define WINDOW VIEWPLANE*2
#define FOCALDIST 1000
#define RADIUS 200

//#define _ANIMATE

// typedef enum {false=0, true=1} BOOL;
// typedef enum {down=0, up=1} DIRECTION;

#define CRED 0
#define CGREEN 1
#define CBLUE 2
#define true 1
#define false 0

/* --------------- VECTORS -------------------- */

typedef struct Vector3D{
    cl_double x;
    cl_double y;
    cl_double z;
    cl_double dummy1;
} VECTOR3D;

typedef struct ray {
    VECTOR3D origin;
    VECTOR3D direction;
} RAY;

/* ------------------- PIXEL ------------------ */
typedef struct pixel {
    RAY ray;
    cl_double rgb[4];
    cl_int i;
    cl_int j;
    cl_int dummy1;
    cl_int dummy2;
    cl_int dummy3;
    cl_int dummy4;
    cl_int dummy5;
    cl_int dummy6;
} PIXEL;

/* ----------------- VIEWPORT ----------------- */
typedef struct vp {
    cl_int xvmin;
    cl_int yvmin;
    cl_int xvmax;
    cl_int yvmax;
    PIXEL* pPixels;
} VIEWPORT;

/* ---------------- SPHERE -------------------- */

typedef struct sp_intersection {
    cl_double   lambda_in;
    cl_double   lambda_out;
    VECTOR3D    normal;
    VECTOR3D point;
    cl_int  valid;
} SPHERE_INTERSECTION;

typedef struct sph {
    VECTOR3D center;
    cl_double radius;
    cl_double kd_rgb[3];
    cl_double ks_rgb[3];
    cl_double ka_rgb[3];
    cl_double shininess;
    cl_int mirror;
}SPHERE;


/* ------------------- RAY --------------------- */


/* --------------- VECTOR BASIS ---------------- */
typedef struct vb {
    VECTOR3D u;
    VECTOR3D v;
    VECTOR3D n;
} VEC_BASIS;

#endif
In kernel:

typedef struct pixel {
    RAY ray;
    double rgb[4];
    int i;
    int j;
    int dummy1;
    int dummy2;
    int dummy3;
    int dummy4;
    int dummy5;
    int dummy6;
} PIXEL;
```

And kernel:

```
typedef struct Vector3D {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double dummy1;
} VECTOR3D;

typedef struct ray {
    VECTOR3D origin;
    VECTOR3D direction;
} RAY;

typedef struct pixel {
    RAY ray;
    double rgb[4];
    int i;
    int j;
    int dummy1;
    int dummy2;
    int dummy3;
    int dummy4;
    int dummy5;
    int dummy6;
} PIXEL;

void vec_sub(VECTOR3D *v1, VECTOR3D *v2, VECTOR3D *v3) {
    v1->x = v2->x - v3->x;
    v1->y = v2->y - v3->y;
    v1->z = v2->z - v3->z;
}

void vec_add(VECTOR3D *v1, VECTOR3D *v2, VECTOR3D *v3) {
    v1->x = v2->x + v3->x;
    v1->y = v2->y + v3->y;
    v1->z = v2->z + v3->z;
}


void vec_scale(double scale, VECTOR3D *v1, VECTOR3D *v2) {
    v1->x = scale * v2->x;
    v1->y = scale * v2->y;
    v1->z = scale * v2->z;
}

double dotproduct(VECTOR3D *v1, VECTOR3D *v2) {

    return v1->x * v2->x + v1->y * v2->y + v1->z * v2->z;
}

void normalize_vector(VECTOR3D *v) {

    double magnitude;

    // 1. calculate the magnitude (length):
    magnitude = sqrt( dotproduct(v, v) );

    // 2. normalize the vector:
    v->x = v->x / magnitude;
    v->y = v->y / magnitude;
    v->z = v->z / magnitude;
}


__kernel void compute_ray(
        write_only global PIXEL *output,
        VECTOR3D view_point,
        VECTOR3D camera_frame_n,
        VECTOR3D camera_frame_u,
        VECTOR3D camera_frame_v,
        const int viewport_xvmin,
        const int viewport_yvmin,
        const double distance,
        const int w, const int h
)
{
    float u, v;
    VECTOR3D v1, v2, v3, v4, dir;
    RAY ray;
    PIXEL pixel;

    int gi = get_global_id(0);
    int i = gi / w;
    int j = gi % w;

    u = (float)(viewport_xvmin) + (float)(i) + 0.5f;
    v = (float)(viewport_yvmin) + (float)(j) + 0.5f;

    vec_scale(-distance, &v1, &camera_frame_n);
    vec_scale(u, &v2, &camera_frame_u);
    vec_scale(v, &v3, &camera_frame_v);

    ray.origin.x = 22;
    ray.origin.y = 22;
    ray.origin.z = 22;

    vec_add(&v4, &v1, &v2);
    vec_add(&dir, &v4, &v3);
    normalize_vector(&dir);

    ray.direction.x = 11;
    ray.direction.y = 11;
    ray.direction.z = 11;

    pixel.ray = ray;
    pixel.i = 33;
    pixel.j = 33;

    output[i*w*j] = pixel;
}
```

I intentionally set i, j, origin and direction structures to fixed number so I could see if numbers are set.

Then I try to get pixel set on GPU in line

> pCurrentPixel = &pPixels[i*VPWIDTH+j];

but pCurrentPixel->i for example is 0 instead of 33.

Code compiles with following commands:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c shading.c -o shading.o
gcc -c sphere.c -o sphere.o
gcc -c ray.c -o ray.o
gcc -c vectors.c -o vectors.o
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu main.o shading.o sphere.o ray.o vectors.o -lGL -lglut -lGLU -lX11 -lm -lrt -lOpenCL -o main
```

Comment: if it is array of structs you write, it could be undefined behaviour. Pixel for example, may not be same sized as in device in host and may need different alignments.

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mcve]. In the code you've provided, It's not clear what `output[i*w*j]` means. Are `i`, `w`, and `j` meant to be indexes? How are these values derived? How is `pixel` computed? On top of that, where in the code have you assigned `output` as an argument for your kernel? There is not nearly enough information provided here to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Added additional info.

Comment: We still need more. With a [mcve], emphasis should be put on the *Complete and Verifiable* parts of that idiom. I understand the project itself might be huge, but just putting `...` between sections of code makes it extremely unclear how components connect to each other. Is the section that assigns arguments part of the same function as the part that submits them, or are they separated into different functions? If so, how are those functions called? You should probably err on the side of providing enough code that we could plausibly compile it ourselves with a properly configured environment.

Comment: Added almost complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting the right VPWIDTH and VPHEIGHT `output[i*w*j] = pixel;` had to be changed to `output[i*w+j] = pixel;` in C code.